# Wrong JRE in a JavaScript Project Imported Into Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven

I imported a maven project into Eclipse. It is a JavaScript project, but still I get the following warnings:
 - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
- The compiler compliance specified is 1.5 but a JRE 1.8 is used

I examined the pom.xml, but did not find a:
maven-compiler-plugin

and not even the string 1.5.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

I did see something strange. When I go to the properties of the project I see:

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r52n.png)

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4rn.png)

[Order and Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtS7A.png)

The strange thing is src/main/java and src/test java do not exist. So why are they included into the project?

When I remove those two paths and the JRE System library everything is clean.
But the code is going to be distributed and we do not want that everyone has to do these clean-up actions.
What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

It is only partly true that removing the paths and JRE System library makes thing clean. When I do:
Maven -> Update Project

I get the old problem back again.

---

Edit on the comment of @greg-449.

I created a pom.xml that is as clean as I can create it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Foo Client Application</name>
    <description>The Foot client, enabling local users and remote partners to work together.</description>
    <url>https://www.Foo.net/</url>
    <groupId>net.Foo.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>Foo-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

I see nothing wrong with this pom.xml. But I am still getting the same messages.
So why do I keep getting those messages?

Comment: Someone told me the problem is that Eclipse thinks that the project is a Java/JavaSript project, while it is an HTML/JavaScript project. Could this be the case? If so: what can I do about it?

Comment: If you have 'Java Build Path' in the project properties then Eclipse thinks this is a Java project. These are nothing to do with Javascript. You might want to create a new project which is Javascript only (or one of the 'Web' projects).

Comment: @greg-449 It is a project that is more as a decade in the running. I am not allowed to just create a new pom.xml I am afraid. I had searched for compiler directives, but did not find any. I just now saw there was also JUnit dependency. What seemed a bit odd. But removing this did not change things. I look further in the pom.xml to see if there is anything that would explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse does not handle imported maven projects correctly. It seems it supposes that these are always Java projects.
When I create and import the following pom.xml (and nothing beside this pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Foo Client Application</name>
    <description>The Foo client, enabling local users and remote partners to work together.</description>
    <url>https://www.Foo.com/</url>
    <groupId>com.Foo.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>Foo-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

I have the same problems. So it looks like it is impossible to solve without changing Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven, you should better to use a JDK instead of a JRE.

Try in you build path : Right click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build path

Remove the JRE and add a JDK

Comment: That only removes one of the messages. And when I do 'Maven -> Update Project' it returns. Also the problem is that people need to do things after they imported the project. We want this not to be necessary.